# Empty page with Firefox (all OS) and Nginx

Tags: linux, nginx, firefox

I don't understand why, but I only have an empty page with Firefox (iOS, MacOS X and Windows last versions) when I use the code below. The same code works perfectly with Safari and IE. Could you explain why ?
I test my Nginx configuration with https://www.ssllabs.com and I get A+. So I don't understand what is wrong.

When I use the Firefox web console mode, I get :

- Error: call to Function() blocked by CSP
- Content Security Policy alerts

```
server {
    listen 443;
    ssl on;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;

    ssl_certificate      /certificate/mywebsite/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /certificate/mywebsite/privkey.pem;

    ssl_session_cache none;
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    ssl_stapling on;
    resolver 80.67.169.12 valid=30s;
    resolver_timeout 5s;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /certificate/mywebsite/chain.pem;

    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparam.pem;

    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers '!kEECDH+ECDSA+AES128 kEECDH+ECDSA+AES256 !kEECDH+AES128 kEECDH+AES256 !kEDH+AES128 kEDH+AES256 +SHA !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !kECDH !DSS !MD5 !RC4 !EXP !PSK !SRP !CAMELLIA !SEED';

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload";
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src https://mywebsite:443"; 
    add_header X-Frame-Options "DENY"; 
    add_header X-Xss-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
    add_header 'Referrer-Policy' 'no-referrer';

    server_name mywebsite;
    server_tokens off;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/restyaboard;
    index  index.html index.php;
    client_max_body_size 300M;

    rewrite ^/oauth/authorize$ /server/php/authorize.php last;
    rewrite ^/oauth_callback/([a-zA-Z0-9_\.]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_\.]*)$ /server/php/oauth_callback.php?plugin=$1&code=$2 last;
    rewrite ^/download/([0-9]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_\.]*)$ /server/php/download.php?id=$1&hash=$2 last;
    rewrite ^/ical/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/([a-z0-9]*).ics$ /server/php/ical.php?board_id=$1&user_id=$2&hash=$3 last;
    rewrite ^/api/(.*)$ /server/php/R/r.php?_url=$1&$args last;
    rewrite ^/api_explorer/api-docs/$ /client/api_explorer/api-docs/index.php last;

    location / {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html/restyaboard/client;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload"; #Activation de HSTS
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src https://mywebsite:443"; 
    add_header X-Frame-Options "DENY"; 
    add_header X-Xss-Protection "1; mode=block"; 
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"; 
    add_header 'Referrer-Policy' 'no-referrer'; 
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass    unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index   index.php;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "upload_max_filesize=9G \n post_max_size=9G \n max_execution_time=200 \n max_input_time=200 \n memory_limit=256M";
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload"; 
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src https://mywebsite:443"; 
    add_header X-Frame-Options "DENY"; 
    add_header X-Xss-Protection "1; mode=block"; 
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"; 
    add_header 'Referrer-Policy' 'no-referrer'; 
    }

    location ~* \.(css|js|less|html|ttf|woff|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|ico) {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html/restyaboard/client;
            if (-f $request_filename) {
                    break;
            }
            rewrite ^/img/([a-zA-Z_]*)/([a-zA-Z_]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_\.]*)$ /server/php/image.php?size=$1&model=$2&filename=$3 last;
            add_header        Cache-Control public;
            add_header        Cache-Control must-revalidate;
            expires           7d;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload"; 
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src https://mywebsite:443"; 
    add_header X-Frame-Options "DENY"; 
    add_header X-Xss-Protection "1; mode=block"; 
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"; 
    add_header 'Referrer-Policy' 'no-referrer'; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the Content-Security-Policy header you send.

The header is not evaluated by Internet Explorer at all, that's why it works there.
I'm not sure why it works for Safari, however Firefox seems to enforce it and it isn't compatible to the content you serve.

To debug this further you will have to look at the Content Security Policy alerts in Firefox and change either your content to match the policy or adapt the policy to the needs of your content.

If you provide the alerts, maybe we can have a look at this.

Comment: Hello, many thanks for your answer. Please find below the Firefox alerts.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot see any of the firefox alerts you've posted.

Comment: Sorry, someone deleted the Firefox alerts and I can't add it in my initial question because of the number of characters. How I can transfert you these informations ?